# Login fails,when credentials are saved in chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I'm working on web based application,while login chrome asks to 'remember password', when I do save it & login again with the saved password, the login fails.

Few things I observed:
1. Its browser specific, works fine in other browsers.
2. when i tried to show the password from chrome settings, its into the encrypted format.

I dont know how to tackle this issue.

Any help would be greatful!

Comment: it'll be hard for anyone to help you if you don't post code on how it's done.